# How long does it normally take for a 700MB update to install?

Tags: software-update, leopard, powerpc, power-mac

I've been waiting for a little over an hour for it to install. I am using a PowerMac G5 dual-core with leopard.

Comment: what is a "while" 5min or 30 minutes or 3 hours ?

Comment: About a little over an hour...

Comment: It still says installing  1 item, configuring installation

Comment: Should I leave it on until it is done? But I hasn't moved in a bit almost 2 hours now

Comment: wait another hour or 2, maybe it gets unstuck before you kill the install process, since that can not so funny results.

Comment: I will actually leave it on overnight and just reinstall OS X if I have to kill the install

Comment: Cancelled it by shutting the system down... my mac can't run 10.5.8.......

Comment: Happy Ending :)

Comment: Maybe you make that a answer! so we are all square in here. Obviously the reason is when Apple switched from PowerPC-CPU to Intel CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not long to start the install. Open the log file and look for progress. Command-L and then Command-3 shows all details.

Comment: I fixed the issue... my mac can't do the combo update to OS X leopard 10.5.8 system doesn't support it...

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your internet speed, such as a slow 3mbps (megabits, not megabytes per second) or a fast 40mbps. You can calculate the time it should take by dividing your connection speed (in megabits) by 8 (8 bits in a byte), then dividing your download size (in megabytes) by that number. I use an iPhone app called Ookla Speedtest, it's free, but ad-supported and seems to work well.